# Once a user is logged into Firebase with email & password auth can I use google auth to link the users Youtube videos?

Tags: authentication, youtube, firebase, google-oauth, angularfire

I was trying to link/merge auth providers in Firebase but instead, I was wondering if this work around would give me similar results.

Can I log a user in with the Firebase email & password auth and then on their profile page use the google auth so that I can grab their access token to access their youtube videos?

Then when I set the user I will use their password and email but pass in the google uid for future use so that I can access their videos.

// Updated question with code example

So initially, I was just signing users in with google and passing in the youtube parameters so that I could access the users videos. This is my Firebase auth with google function below.

```
  $scope.authWithGoogle = function() {
    var scope = {
      scope:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
    };
    Auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect("google", scope).then(function(authData) {
      $scope.loggedInUser = authData;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      if(error.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
        Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("google", scope).then(function(authData) {
          $scope.loggedInUser = authData;
        });
      } else {
      console.log(error);
     }
    });
  };
```

This just authenticates the user and doesn't store anything in the data..I think. So now I was hoping to implement a login with email and password so that everyone could login even if they didn't have a google account.

I was just wondering if I could authenticate the user with email and password and then once they are signed in use this function to allow the user to authenticate with google and link their videos to their account? Then when I set my user data I can save their access token for the videos so that I have access to them later. I was just wondering if this was a possible work around instead of trying to link email and password with a google account or if it is too hacky.

Ultimately if I can log in a user with email and password and then link their google account once they are signed in that would be the desired behavior I am going for but I just haven't been able to find how to do this.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean here. Can you add some code that demonstrates what you've already done and what you're having trouble with?

Comment: Hey Frank thank you for the response I have updated the question to hopefully clarify my question a little better. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

On Firebase Authentication, a user can be signed in to only one identity provider at a time. So they can be signed in to either email+password, or google, in your use-case, not to both.

It is possible to have the user sign-in to Google authentication without using Firebase Authentication and then associate the two yourself. But since this is not built-in to Firebase, there is no documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I wasn't sure if this was possible or not so I wanted to make sure before I headed down that road.